# Replacing HTML then adding a document fragment back into the html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range, selection

I am trying to create a highlighter tool which works like this:

- A user first selects a range of text.
- They then click one of the color buttons and the background of the selected text is highlighted
- Then they select another range of text...
- Now when they click the button all of the html is replaced with the cached version of the html (no highlights)
- Then the new selected text that has been highlighted is appended back into the fresh html.

This way only one range of text can be highlighted at a time.

**Problem:**

I am having a hard time understanding the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range), [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node) API's

At the moment I can't add the highlighted text back into the fresh html... I am only appending it to the document.body.

**What I have so far:**

https://jsfiddle.net/4mb39jd6/

```
(function(){

  var highlighter = {

    /**
     *
     */
    init: function(){
      this.cacheDOM();
      this.bindEvents();
    },

    /**
     *
     */
    cacheDOM: function(){
      this.$html           = $('.content').html();
      this.$content        = $('.content');
      this.$highlighter    = $('.highlighter');
    },

    /**
     *
     */
    bindEvents: function(){
      this.$highlighter.on('mousedown', this.highlightSelection.bind(this));
    },

    /**
     *
     */
    highlightSelection: function(e){

      var selection = window.getSelection();          // get selection
      var text      = selection.toString();           // get selected text
      var newNode   = document.createElement('span'); // create node

      newNode.style.backgroundColor = $(e.target).css('backgroundColor'); // set node properties
      newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));                 // append selection text to node

      var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);      // 2 - get the selected range
      range.deleteContents();                   // delete the contents
      range.insertNode(newNode);                // insert the new node with the replacement text
      documentFragment = range.cloneContents(); // clone the node

      this.$content.html(this.$html);              // refresh the content
      document.body.appendChild(documentFragment); // add the new highlighted text
    },
  };
  highlighter.init();

})();
```

**Q:**

How do I add my highlighted node... which looks like this `<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 131);">some random text</span>` back into a fresh html document so that it is in the same position.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to clone the whole content? Commenting out the last three lines in `highlightSection` seems to produce the desired behavior... https://jsfiddle.net/wxrxf6r1/

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I only want one selected section of text at any one given moment... as it is I can highlight all over the place... I only want to be able to select one range at a time.

Comment: Did you have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)?

Comment: I saw that... trying to do this bare bones for educational reasons... but this is something I will examine closer if I can't get a workable solution going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to have only one highlight at a time, I'd go for a less complicated approach that:

- When adding a highlight,
- Checks the html for the previous highlight,
- Removes it when found

To do so, mark your highlight `<span>`s with an attribute or class (or better yet, store a reference):

```
newNode.classList.add("js-highlight");
```

Add a method to remove such an element:

```
clearHighlight: function() {
  var selection = document.querySelector(".js-highlight");

  if (selection) {
    selection.parentElement.replaceChild(
      document.createTextNode(selection.innerText),
      selection  
    );
  }
}
```

Then, before replacing your `range` with the highlight element, call `clearHighlight`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2tqdLfb1/

**An alternative:**

I also tried another approach that respected your "cached HTML" logic, but found it to be overcomplicated. The basics of that approach:

- Check the query-path for the `parentElement` of the selection
- Store the start index and end index of the selection
- Replace the HTML by the cached HTML string
- Find the newly injected parent element of the selection via the stored query-path
- Split its `innerText` in to 1, 2 or 3 `textNodes` based on the selection start and end index
- Replace the textNode that represents the selection by your highlight `<span>`

An example that shows how you could store the query path for your range ancestor:

```
function getPathUpToSelector(selector, element, path) {
  var parent = element.parentElement;

  if (parent && !element.matches(selector)) {
    var index = Array.from(parent.children).indexOf(element) + 1;
    path.push("*:nth-child(" + index + ")");

    return getPathUpToSelector(selector, parent, path);
  }

  return [selector].concat(path).join(" > ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is FANTASTIC. I was over-complicating things and this works well. Only issue now is that if I select text over two nodes then the HTML markup is destroyed... I have started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656501/serializing-html-placing-span-elements-around-selected-text-while-preserving-th