# Serializing html: placing span elements around selected text while preserving the HTML structure

Tags: javascript, html, dom, serialization, selection

I am trying to make a text highlighter where a teacher can select a range of text so that the student can follow along. The text is formatted with HTML so there are `<p>`, `<b>`, `<em>` etc... elements.

To highlight the range of text I am wrapping the range in a span element.

**The issue:**

https://jsfiddle.net/7fedkobr/1/

Here is a sentence with some HTML markup:

```
<p>The <b>quick</b> brown fox jumps over the <em>lazy</em> dog</p>
```

When I select a word such as 'The' it gets wrapped in a `<span>`, boom, no problem.

The issues come when I try and select over any html tags... for example if I select the entire sentence then I lose ALL my mark-up.

**What I am looking for.**

A method to serialize the spans so that they fall in-between the html elements and wrap all the text.

Using the previous example: if I select the entire sentence above then I would get the following output:

```
<p><span>The </span><b><span>quick</span></b><span> brown fox jumps over the </span><em><span>lazy</span></em><span> dog</span></p>
```

**Q:**

Is there a method for this kind of serialization? I can't find anything in the jQuery docs and the few people I have asked were stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use **[`range.extractContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/extractContents)**. The documentation states the most important part for your needs:

> Partially selected nodes are cloned to include the parent tags
>   necessary to make the document fragment valid.

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
        span = document.createElement('span');

    span.className = 'highlight';
    span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
    range.insertNode(span);
});
```

```css
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="test">
    Select any part of <b>this sentence and</b> and then move the mouse to a new location.
</div>
```

You can see in the picture below that the resulting HTML from a selection does exactly what you are asking:

[image: DOM representation of selection.]

Comment: Just, wow. That is exactly the magic that I was looking for! Only problem is draggin the highlight over like an h1 to a p... yikes! https://jsfiddle.net/7fedkobr/2/ Gonna have to think about that one.. it seems like this highlighting business is a bit like 'chasing your tail'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need jquery for that, plain CSS will do the trick:

```
*::selection { background-color: yellow !important; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer I appreciate it, but this is not what I am asking.

Comment: Yrw, I guess this is what got me confused then: I am trying to make a text highlighter where a teacher can select a range of text so that the student can follow along.

Comment: No worries! Appreciate the intent!